# first time loading of sub url that needs data from server in react app using React Router v4.3 and create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-v4

I already fetch data from API on main app page `localhost:3000/products-list`.
I can then navigate to different products pages using React Router.

However, when I try to navigate directly to a product page like `localhost:3000/product-a` for the first time and since the data is not stored in browser localStorage (considering this is the first time the user uses the app), I get error that I am referencing an unidentified object.

So my reasoning is that I need to fetch data from server for this specific product so that its page is able to render.

Or is this usually handled differently by redirecting the call to `localhost:3000` so the App can initialize properly then it will route the call to `localhost:3000/product-a` using React Router?

Or Do I need to set up server side rendering for this to work?

Comment: You can pass props, in this case your product data, using react router, https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/ to save a request to the backend. But, your product page should also be able to get data on its own. What if someone bookmarks the page?

Comment: @DCTID my problem is about accessing it directly like when someone uses a bookmark or visits the page through a shared link. I read about routing urls [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually) but this is old and not sure it still applies. but in case it does, I understand from it that the app should redirect to main page, load all the relevant data, then execute route to the corresponding product page with the relevant data. But I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Why not just make the prop optional and if the component renders without that prop, then make a request for that specific product. It simplifies it and is probably a better user experience.

Comment: @DCTID Thanks. I implemented your suggestion and it worked perfectly. I will add sample code for those facing similar problems

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it thanks to suggestion from @DCTID.
On refresh, the component renders even if the data is not available from the server (although the data would be missing. Once data is fetched from server it will show)
If a persisted state is used, then data will not be fetched on subsequent refresh.

```
class SingleProduct extends Component {
//first I check if the product list is available. If not, I fetch it from server
//by calling a thunk  
  componentDidMount(){
    if (_.isEmpty(this.props.products)){
      this.props.injectThunk()
    }
}

render(){

  let id=this.props.match.params.id//Product ID from using React Router
  //Then I find the relevant product by looking for its ID in the product list
//I can then display the product properties    
    return (
      <div>
      {product.title}
      {product.price}
       etc...
      </div>
)}
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {
            products: state.products,
                   };
  }

  export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{injectThunk})(SingleProduct))
```